# Calling external JavaScript functions from HTML with XML DOM

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I know how to call a JavaScript function from my HTML document but I can't seem to get it to work, as I'm using XML DOM within the project, therefore I want to call the load function of my XML file, but also on page load I want to put the data into the relevant fields.
I call my JavaScript file as usual using the below within the  tags.

```
<script src ="functions.js"></script>
```

Within the JavaScript file I have two functions:

```js
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
function displayInfo()
```

In `displayInfo()`, I have multiple information gathering such as

```js
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('blogPost');
i = 0;

title = x[i].getElementsByTagName("postTitle")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
```

Which then puts the information into the relevant place using the ID. From what I understand, I want to call `displayInfo()` using `onload`, within the body tag, but then I'm not sure how to call the function to load the file, as I think usually that'd be after the body tag, which would then mean they'd be called the wrong way round.

Comment: Why don't you call both `loadXMLDoc()` and `displayInfo()` (in that order) from the `onload` callback?

Comment: @bgoldst like <body onload= "loadXMLDoc(filename); displayInfo()">?

Comment: yes, something like that, although I would suggest writing a separate function to take over when the event triggers, just so you don't have to start embedding lots of JavaScript into the HTML attribute. So you could do `<body onload="onloadHandler();">` and then in `onloadHandler()` you could execute `displayInfo(loadXMLDoc(filename));`. Here I've assumed that `loadXMLDoc()` returns the `xmlDoc` object that `displayInfo();` requires.